# how i deploy .netframework on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure-cloud-services, .net-framework-version

I've written the following code in .NET that runs well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Good Morning");
            Console.Write("Bad Morning");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to deploy this code on Azure cloud.

I have a Virtual Machine but do not have an idea how I can deploy.

Comment: `I have a Virtual Machine but do not have an idea how I can deploy.` What does it mean?

Comment: I will post an answer about the difference between azure cloud services and virtual machine in the deployment process. Hope it helps you understand.

Comment: Is there any other place I need help with deploying azure cloud services? Does my answer help you?

Comment: No,I try to publish azure web job in VS2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

***WebJob***

I also updated the Webjob posting tutorial in the answer. Please read carefully for cloud services below.

Generally webjob creation is for web app service, if you want to create it separately, the following 5 screenshots will show you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Azure Cloud Services***

1. First create cloud services on the portal to ensure that your subscription has permission to create classic applications.
2. For the follow-up operation, see the 12 screenshots behind me, and record every step of the operation in detail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So far, using vs2019 to release cloud services operation and testing is all over. For more details and methods, please check the official documentation.

**PRIVIOUS**

In [Azure Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me), we don't need to create virtual machines. Instead, you provide a configuration file that tells Azure how many of each you'd like, such as "three web role instances" and "two worker role instances." The platform then creates them for you.

When you [deployed your apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal), you will get a VM which just for your program. The VM here is not like a Virtual Machine created directly. The VM in Cloud Services is generated based on the configuration file, and it is not recommended to use it directly as a server VM. Therefore, your virtual machine will not be used when deploying Cloud Services.

If you have a virtual machine, it can be used directly as a server. To deploy your application, you only need to log in remotely, just deploy it like a server computer.

Comment: @JaiMahesh I will see your another post later.